# I'm trying to import a ZIP file via the built-in 'Open With...' function and not other default files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uti

Here's what I have added to my **Info.plist** file:[image]

I want to give open in... functionality only for zip file types but as I am giving 
com.pkware.zip-archive , all default file types are supported which I don't want.
I want to support only zip not docx, pptx, xls, etc.

Any suggestion accepted